# How to restrict what children tags should be by using attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an snippet XML like this:

```
....
<cell type='1'>
    <A>Some text</A>
</cell>
<cell type='2'>
    <B>Some text</B>
</cell>
....
```

How to write a schema that enforces element A to be a child of 'cell' only when 'type' attribute is 1 (B if 2) ?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry but I think the current XSD doesn't allow this.

the only way to define choice or alternative is by using the [xsd:choice](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_choice.asp) tag.  this only specify which elements to choose from and the cardinality (maximum and minimum occurrence) of these, but not on some conditions.

so its only about the *which* and *how much* elements but surely *not on which conditions* to choose from